# Typescript Error in use of generic type that extends associative array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

If I have this code:

```js
interface IAssociativeArray {
    [key: string]: any;
}

function Do<T extends IAssociativeArray>(p: T) {
    p.someProp = "someValue";
}

function Do2(p: IAssociativeArray) {
    p.someProp = "someValue";
}
```

`Do` fails with the error: ***Property 'someProp' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339)*** ?

But `Do2` does not. Why is this?

PS. I use Typescript 3.6.3, it works OK in versions before 3.5.1

Comment: Hmm, looks like this issue appears only in last Typescript versions. It doesn't fail in 3.3.3

Comment: Does fail in [`3.5.1`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.5.1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEDOmD2DhxjABuE6UUcAnsgN4BQyTyA2gNYRUBcymYUoAOYBdHnBBUA3PQC+9ejACuIBERwhkAERwAeACrIIAD0ggAJpjRZc+QiTIVqAPgAUABx56AlHUbM3AHS4ALYQAApQOG7IALzIAEQhEABqcAA2ihDx0nIKyqrA6lo4AEzuPBjYeAREpOSUVD4MzMiBSRFRsQlJqRlZOfRAA)

Comment: It seems this is by design https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769

Comment: Interesting, certainly seems like a good decision!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was introduced by design to avoid unsound narrowing. [More details](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769)